# Old qualifier problem clarification (Probability related)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

I'm trying to make sense of what is being asked in the question. What does the set $E_{n}^{\epsilon}$ represent?

Let $\mathbb{P}$ be a probability measure on $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Let $\mathbb{P}^{\infty}$ be the corresponding infinite product on $(\mathbb{R}^{\infty}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{\infty})$). Define the set $E_{n}^{\epsilon} := \{x=(x_{1},x_{2},...);|x_{n}|>\epsilon\}$. Assume that $\mathbb{P}(\{0\}) < 1$. Show that for some $\epsilon > 0$,

$\mathbb{P}^{\infty}$($\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}E_{n}^{\epsilon}) = 1$

or equivalently,

$\mathbb{P}^{\infty}$($\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}(E_{n}^{\epsilon})^{c}) = 0$

My initial guess was to use Borel-Cantelli, but the conditions of the lemma do not seem to be satisfied in this question.

EDITED: Changed norm to absolute value in $E_{n}^{\epsilon}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the norm should actually be an absolute value.

On the probablity space $(\mathbb{R}^{\infty}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{\infty},\mathbb P^{\infty} )$, we can consider an independent sequence of random variable $(X_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ by $X_n\left(\left(x_j\right)_{j\geqslant 1}\right) :=x_n$.

Comment: Thank you. Could you help me understand what the set $E_{n}^{\epsilon}$ represents?

Comment: The sequences whose absolute value of the $n$th term if greater than $\varepsilon$.